# Logical OR in mutiple condition with a nil expression

Tags: swift, null, conditional-statements, logical-or

Since 30 minutes I'm looking for a compiling solution for this objective-c condition that I want write in swift

```
if (session == nil || ![session isValid]) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times, `![aThing aMethod]` in Objective-C will translate to `!aThing.aMethod` in Swift.

Also, no need to wrap the boolean condition in parenthesis anymore.

```
if session == nil || !session.isValid {

}
```

Comment: waouh! I was sure to tested that. I'm so ashamed for asking this question :(

Answer (score 0):

If `session` is an optional, you can force unwrap it:

```
if session == nil || !session!.isValid() {

}
```